# JDK Installed but browser (FF, IE) can't run Java apps

Tags: java

I have installed latest JDK (x64) on Windows 7 but browsers still can't run the java apps. I understand that JDK includes JRE. JDK is installed correctly and from command line (Java -version) shows installed version as well. Any suggestion please? Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You also need a browser plugin: http://java.sun.com/products/plugin/. This plugin is installed when you use the java installer. If you just copy the directories over and set up you PATH environment variable, the command line will work but not the browser.

Answer (score 0):

I've recently seen this problem related to the use of a 32-bit rather than a 64-bit web browser.

The default version of most web-browsers is currently 32-bit, regardless of the 64-bit operating system.

In this case, also installing the 32-bit java runtime environment(JRE) is recommended, as described here for windows (https://www.java.com/en/download/faq/java_win64bit.xml).

After installation, type `java -version` in the console, which should confirm that the Windows 7 PATH variables still refer to 64-bit version of Java from the JDK.

Another promising option is to switch to a 64-bit browser (e.g. Chrome-64bit, Waterfox).